# Is the definite article omitted in this sentence?

Tags: articles, definite-article, possessives

I ran into this sentence in a Fortune article:

> The life sciences arm of Google umbrella company Alphabet is bugging out.

Is the definite article missing in this sentence? Should it be written as:

> The life sciences arm of **the** Google umbrella company Alphabet is bugging out.

or

> The life sciences arm of Google's umbrella company Alphabet is bugging out.

Comment: In my opinion, no, the article is not missing.  Yes, *company* is a countable, singular noun, so it needs a determiner, but "Google umbrella company" functions as that determiner.

Comment: @stangdon I think you meant _"Google umbrella"_ is the determiner preceding the noun "company."

Comment: whoops, you're right.

Comment: All your examples need commas.

The life sciences arm of Google umbrella company, Alphabet, is…

The life sciences arm of the Google umbrella company, Alphabet, is…

The life sciences arm of Google's umbrella company, Alphabet, is…

Sorry, but even if it didn’t need those commas, Google umbrella-company Alphabet would be analogous at best to to US-Senator Joe Shmoe, if not to US Senator Joe-Shmoe.

Answer (score 1):

**umbrella company** specifies a *role* (and role nouns do not have an article). You could hyphenate it **umbrella-company**.

**Google** is a noun modifying the role noun "adjectivally" (noun-adjunct, premodifier, attributive noun).

**Google umbrella-company Alphabet** is analogous to **US Senator Joe Shmoe**.